# Book with a crazy cult which eats vat-grown flesh of Jesus for Communion

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I think this book came out 5-10 years ago.  It's a near-future dystopia that takes place in a very Balkanized America.  There's a teenage boy who lives with his family in a gated community compound.  He decides to go "over the wall" and, once outside, he gets kidnapped by a crazy cult who feeds its members what is supposedly the vat-grown flesh of Jesus (cloned from Jesus' DNA).  I've been looking but I'm starting to think I must have hallucinated the whole thing!  I would appreciate any help immeasurably...

Comment: Can you remember any names of people or places, or any other such specific words that might help a search?

Comment: I wish I could, but no, all I do remember is the weird premise...

Comment: If you hallucinated the eating the flesh of Jesus bit, the rest of the story is Theodore Cogswell's [The Wall Around the World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wall_Around_the_World).

Answer (score 2):

There is a story called "Eating Jesus Christ" from 2005 by Hugh Cook.

Comment: Can you add some information outlining why you think it may be this story?

Comment: It certainly isn't the right one. There's a full copy of the text here; http://web.archive.org/web/20070301033141/http://zenvirus.com/stories/eating-jesus-christ.html and it's nothing like what was described by the OP.